# Wiring a capacitive touch sensor to the Arduino?

Tags: arduino, sensor, integrated-circuit, capsense

I have just recently bought a few different ic's from Mouser.com, not thinking i never even looked to see if i could use them. I Wound up getting a few [Azoteq IQS128 capacitive touch sensors](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Azoteq/IQS128-00100TSR/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsVh0scArXy33KTkQUiErW79jTEy/lkOkw=), but I have absolutely no clue which pins are which and how to wire them to an arduino. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the datasheed? It's a load of informations about using the component. But to wire it phisically you need to put the smt package in something that can fit with Arduino...which means a small board or a socket

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet is available on http://www.azoteq.com - see the pinout there.

The effective operation of the IQS128 is dependent on good de-coupling at the VDDHI and VREG lines (see the reference designs)

If you have ordered 957-IQS12800100TSR you will have a proximity output on pin3.

If you have ordered 957-IQS12800000TSR then pin3 is an input (ENABLE/DISABLE). You will have to pull pin3 high in order to enable the IQS128.

See [the manual](http://www.azoteq.com/images/stories/pdf/iqs128_ev01_user_manual.pdf) for some information on the layout used on the 957-IQS128EV01.

Buying the 957-IQS128EV01 would give you a module that can be quickly wired/plugged into your design.

Answer (score 1):

Azoteq provides some [design quidelines for capacitive touch sensors](http://www.azoteq.com/images/stories/pdf/azd008_design_guidelines.pdf) as well as a simple [schematic for wiring up the IQS128](http://www.azoteq.com/images/stories/pdf/iqs128_reference_design.pdf). So you would connect your Arduino to the output line. The [breakout board schematics](http://www.azoteq.com/images/stories/pdf/iqs128_ev01_user_manual.pdf) might also give you some ideas.